# Customizing/Extending Liferay Forgot Password Page

Tags: java, liferay

Anyone have any solutions to customizing ForgotPasswordAction? My end goal is to allow users to enter both username or email to be able to retreive their forgotten password. I have overriden the getUser(ActionRequest request) method in the ForgotPassword.java as followed:

```
protected User getUser(ActionRequest actionRequest)
            throws Exception {

            ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(
                WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

            //CUSTOM
            String fgtPass = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "fgtpass");
            String authType = null;

            if (Validator.isNull(authType)) {
                Company company = PortalUtil.getCompany(actionRequest);
                authType = company.getAuthType();
            }

            User user = null;

            if ( fgtPass.indexOf("@") != -1 && fgtPass.indexOf(".") != -1 ) {
                //If the login looks like an email, use the email authType constant.
                authType = CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_EA;
                user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(
                    themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), fgtPass);
            } else {
                //If it doesn't look like an email, use the screen name authType constant.
                authType = CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_SN;
                user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(
                        themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), fgtPass);
            } 

            //End CUSTOM

            return user;
        }
    }
```

This is able to authenticate a user based upon either screen name or email on the initial forgot password screen, but once taken to the reminder query page, it isn't able to process the user. I'm pretty sure that i'm not able to because fgtPass field only exists on the initial forgot password screen and not on the query page. Is there any way to persist this user? Here is the corresponding .jsp:

```
<%
User user2 = (User)request.getAttribute(ForgotPasswordAction.class.getName());

if (Validator.isNull(authType)) {
    authType = company.getAuthType();
    System.out.println(authType);
}

if (user2 == null) {
    System.out.println("User is null.");
} else {
    System.out.println(user2.getScreenName());
}

%>

<portlet:actionURL var="forgotPasswordURL">
    <portlet:param name="saveLastPath" value="0" />
    <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/login/forgot_password" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%= forgotPasswordURL %>" method="post" name="fm">
    <portlet:renderURL var="redirectURL" />

    <aui:input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="<%= redirectURL %>" />

    <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= CaptchaTextException.class %>" message="text-verification-failed" />
    <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= NoSuchUserException.class %>" message='<%= "the-" + TextFormatter.format(authType, TextFormatter.K) + "-you-requested-is-not-registered-in-our-database" %>' />
    <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= RequiredReminderQueryException.class %>" message="you-have-not-configured-a-reminder-query" />
    <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= SendPasswordException.class %>" message="your-password-can-only-be-sent-to-an-external-email-address" />
    <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserEmailAddressException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-email-address" />
    <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserReminderQueryException.class %>" message="your-answer-does-not-match-what-is-in-our-database" />

    <aui:fieldset>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="<%= user2 == null %>">

                <% System.out.println("Enter Test"); %>

                <%
                String loginParameter = null;

                if (authType.equals(CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_EA)) {
                    loginParameter = "emailAddress";
                    System.out.println(loginParameter);
                }
                else if (authType.equals(CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_SN)) {
                    loginParameter = "screenName";
                    System.out.println(loginParameter);
                }
                else if (authType.equals(CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_ID)) {
                    loginParameter = "userId";
                    System.out.println(loginParameter);
                }

                String loginValue = ParamUtil.getString(request, loginParameter);
                %>

                <aui:input name="step" type="hidden" value="1" />

                <aui:input label="login-screen-name-or-email" name="fgtpass" size="30" type="text" value="<%= loginValue %>"  />

                <aui:button-row>
                    <aui:button type="submit" value='<%= PropsValues.USERS_REMINDER_QUERIES_ENABLED ? "next" : "send-new-password" %>' />
                </aui:button-row>

                <% System.out.println("The login value is: " + loginValue); %>

            </c:when>

            <c:when test="<%= (user2 != null) && Validator.isNotNull(user2.getEmailAddress()) %>">
                <aui:input name="step" type="hidden" value="2" />

                <%
                if (user2!=null) {
                    System.out.println("Step 2 " + authType);
                }

                %>

                <aui:input name="emailAddress" type="hidden" value="<%= user2.getEmailAddress() %>" />

                <% System.out.println(user2.getEmailAddress()); %>

                <c:if test="<%= Validator.isNotNull(user2.getReminderQueryQuestion()) && Validator.isNotNull(user2.getReminderQueryAnswer()) %>">
                    <div class="portlet-msg-info">
                        <%= LanguageUtil.format(pageContext, "a-new-password-will-be-sent-to-x-if-you-can-correctly-answer-the-following-question", user2.getEmailAddress()) %>
                    </div>

                <% System.out.println(user2.getReminderQueryAnswer()); %>

                    <aui:input label="<%= user2.getReminderQueryQuestion() %>" name="answer" type="text" />
                </c:if>

                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="<%= PropsValues.USERS_REMINDER_QUERIES_REQUIRED && !user2.hasReminderQuery() %>">
                        <div class="portlet-msg-info">
                            <liferay-ui:message key="the-password-cannot-be-reset-because-you-have-not-configured-a-reminder-query" />
                        </div>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <c:if test="<%= PropsValues.CAPTCHA_CHECK_PORTAL_SEND_PASSWORD %>">
                            <portlet:actionURL windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString() %>" var="captchaURL">
                                <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/login/captcha" />
                            </portlet:actionURL>

                            <liferay-ui:captcha url="<%= captchaURL %>" />
                        </c:if>

                        <aui:button-row>
                            <aui:button type="submit" value='<%= company.isSendPasswordResetLink() ? "send-password-reset-link" : "send-new-password" %>' />
                        </aui:button-row>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <div class="portlet-msg-alert">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="the-system-cannot-send-you-a-new-password-because-you-have-not-provided-an-email-address" />
                </div>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>

<liferay-util:include page="/html/portlet/login/navigation.jsp" />

<aui:script>
    Liferay.Util.focusFormField(document.<portlet:namespace />fm.<portlet:namespace /><%= (user2 == null) ? "emailAddress" : "answer" %>);
</aui:script>
```

Any clues?